# Konva Layer not reporting any events

Tags: javascript, konva

I'm trying to make a Konva Layer clickable, and it's not working. This seems pretty basic, and to my knowledge, I'm doing everything according to the docs.

```
this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
  listening: true,
  container: options.container,
  width: options.container.clientWidth,
  height: options.container.clientHeight,
});
this.waveformLayer = new Konva.Layer({ listening: true });
this.stage.add(this.waveformLayer);

this.waveformLayer.on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Clicking on the waveform layer has no effect. There are rectangles drawn in the layer, I just didn't share that code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is This problem still exits? can u recreate the problem in codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // first we need to create a stage
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: "container", // id of container <div>
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    });
    
    stage.on('click',(e)=>{
    console.log('stage clicked')
    })

    // then create layer
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    layer.on("click", () => {
      console.log("layer");
    });

    // create our shape
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
      x: stage.width() / 2,
      y: stage.height() / 2,
      radius: 70,
      fill: "red",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 4
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(circle);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    // draw the image
    layer.draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      id="container"
      style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid red;"
    ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should add a shape into the layer,like [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fog-xvbo2y?file=/index.html:0-1144)

Comment: There are rectangles drawn within the layer. I just didn't paste that code.

Comment: @ffxsam Please provide a detailed demonstration of your problem.